# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Multi-Location Update

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Using Cloud Functions for Firebase, what is the best way to trigger an update of multiple locations in the hierarchy?  My main goal is to update a value for all users in a list.  I created the following example, which works, but I want to confirm that it is the proper way.

Database Hierarchy:
[Database-Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBNta.png)

This function triggers based off an update and then updates a list of other nodes:

```
exports.multiLocationUpdateTest = functions.database.ref('/atest/update').onWrite(event => {
        console.log('here');
        var mergedUpdate = {};
        mergedUpdate[ 'list/item1/val1' ] = true;
        mergedUpdate[ 'list/item2/val2'  ] = true;
        mergedUpdate[ 'list/item3/val3'  ] = true;

        return event.data.ref.parent.update(mergedUpdate);
 });
```

It will update each of the val1, val2, val3 to true, as expected.

Is this the correct approach and is this guaranteed to be transactional? i.e. is it possible that only val1 gets updated and the others fail?

Comment: So long as all of your updates are batched in a single call they will be applied or rejected atomically. This looks correct to me.

Comment: @KevinDodd If there is something incorrect in your original question, or you have information to add, you can simply edit the question to correct it instead of commenting on your own question.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I edited my original post.  One final question: If the function is long running, will it time out?  Do I need to execute the function within a "Promise"?  I'm still getting familiar with how Firebase functions and Promises work.  I'll continue to research, but I wanted to update the question and response.